# Difference between @Primary vs @Autowired with @Qualifier annotations

Tags: java, spring, annotations

So, if I understood correctly, both are the way to determine which bean to autowire if there are multiple candidates. So what exactly is the difference?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Read [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) as the "default".

If a bean has `@Autowired` *without* any `@Qualifier`, and multiple beans of the type exist, the candidate bean marked `@Primary` will be chosen, i.e. it is the default selection when no other information is available, i.e. when `@Qualifier` is missing.

A good use case is that initially you only had one bean of the type, so none of the code used `@Qualifier`. When you then add another bean, you then also add `@Qualifier` to both the old and the new bean, so any `@Autowired` can choose which one it wants. By also adding `@Primary` to the old original bean, you don't have to add `@Qualifier` to all the existing `@Autowired`. They are "grandfathered" in, so to speak.

`@Primary` is also good if e.g. 95% of `@Autowired` wants a particular bean. That way, only the `@Autowired` that wants the other bean(s) need to specify `@Qualifier`. That way, you have primary beans that all autowired wants, and `@Qualifier` is only used to request an "alternate" bean.

Comment: So you mean, if I have `@Qualifier` and `@Primary`, the former one takes precedence? Spring will first looks for the bean by `@Qualifier` name, if absent, choose the `@Primary` one? If not, the 5% of bean will also be `@Primary` type.

Comment: Yes I just tested and proved my theory. `@Qualifier` > `@Primary` > variable name matching.

Answer (score 7):

`@Qualifier` should be used in conjuction with `@Autowired` always. This will indicate the bean name which needs to be Autowired in case of multiple beans with same type is present in the application context.(so that spring can autowire by name.)

`@Primary` should be used in conjuction with `@Bean` / `@Autowired` which indicates which bean should be given higher preference, when there are multiple beans of same type is present.

One of the classic use cases where you would use `@Primary` is when the framework(example spring-data) expects a bean of some type (example EntityManager) but you have multiple datasources and you would have configured multiple Entity Managers. In such cases `@Qualifier` doesn't quite help.

Comment: I have two datasources, EntityManagers and marked one of them with @Primary but still getting error 'Consider marking one of the beans as Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed". What could be the reason Primary is not effective?

Comment: "One of the classic use cases where you would use @Primary is when the framework(example spring-data) expects a bean of some type (example EntityManager)...." - this is the case because EnityManager beans are not autowired?

Answer (score 5):

**@Qualifier**

If there are more than one instances available for an injection point then we can use `@Qualifier` annotation to resolve an ambiguity. As `@Qualifier` is used at the injection point, there might be two situations where we don't want to or cannot use `@Qualifier`.

1. When autowiring mode is `Autowire.BY_TYPE`. Then, of course, we cannot use `@Qualifier` because we actually don't have user-defined injection point specified as `@Autowired` or `@Inject`
2. We want to do bean selection (i.e. resolve the ambiguity) at
   configuration time rather than during beans development time.

The solution to above problems is to use `@Primary` annotation.

**@Primary**

This Indicates that a particular bean should be given preference when multiple beans are candidates to be autowired to a single-valued dependency. If exactly one 'primary' bean exists among the candidates, it will be the autowired value.

Comment: Could you please give us some concrete examples of the situations you mentioned that can not use Qualifier?