# Spring's @Qualifier is not working

Tags: java, spring

There are two data source configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.proj.killbill.repository.kb", "com.proj.service.base.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "kbEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "kbTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Profile({"dev", "prod"})
public class PersistenceKbConfig {

    @Value("${db.user:default}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${db.password:default}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${db.url:default}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${app.kb.ds.jndi.name}")
    private String kbDsJndiName;

    @Bean(name = "kbDataSource")
    @Profile("dev")
    public DataSource devKbDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "kbDataSource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource prodKbDataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dsLookup.getDataSource(kbDsJndiName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    @Bean(name = "kbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("kbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.proj.service.base.domain");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "kbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager kbTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("kbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.proj.killbill.repository.cm", "com.proj.service.base.repository"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "cmEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "cmTransactionManager")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@Profile({"dev", "prod"})
public class PersistenceCmConfig {

    @Value("${cm.db.user:default}")
    private String user;

    @Value("${cm.db.password:default}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${cm.db.url:default}")
    private String jdbcUrl;

    @Value("${app.cm.ds.jdni.name}")
    private String cmJndiName;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PersistenceCmConfig.class);

    @Bean(name = "cmDataSource")
    @Profile("dev")
    public DataSource devCmDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        LOGGER.debug("CM JDBC URL USER/PASSWORD" + jdbcUrl + " " + user + "/" + password);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "cmDataSource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource prodCmDataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dsLookup.getDataSource(cmJndiName);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
    @Bean(name = "cmEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cmEntityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("cmDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.proj.service.base.domain");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "cmTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager cmTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("cmEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Entity managers use @Qualifier annotations to inject appropriate data sources. But when I start the app I get the exception:

==========

Parameter 0 of method cmEntityManagerFactory in com.proj.killbill.config.PersistenceCmConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - cmDataSource: defined by method 'devCmDataSource' in class path resource [com/proj/killbill/config/PersistenceCmConfig.class]
    - kbDataSource: defined by method 'devKbDataSource' in class path resource [com/proj/killbill/config/PersistenceKbConfig.class]

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

============

@Qualifier("cmDataSource") is just ignored for unknown reason. Why can it be possible?

Comment: It is not ignored. Just declare one of the sources as `@Primary`. `@Qualifier` will inject the correct one. check this for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447779/difference-between-primary-vs-autowired-with-qualifier-annotations

Comment: @pvpkiran Ok, thanks. I just was mislead by spring's message to use EITHER Primary OR Qualifier to resolve the issue.